# R, correlation in p-values

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, p-value

quite new with R and spending lot of time to solve issues...
I have a big table(named `mydata`) containing more that 14k columns. this is a short view...

```
Latitude    comp48109   comp48326   comp48827   comp49708   comp48407   comp48912
59.8    21  29  129 440 23  13
59.8    18  23  32  129 19  34
59.8    19  27  63  178 23  27
53.1    21  28  0   0   26  10
53.1    15  21  129 423 25  36
53.1    18  44  44  192 26  42
48.7    14  32  0   0   17  42
48.7    11  26  0   0   20  33
48.7    24  37  0   0   26  20
43.6    34  40  1   3   23  4
43.6    19  28  0   1   26  33
43.6    19  35  0   0   14  3
41.4    22  67  253 1322    15  4
41.4    44  39  0   0   11  14
41.4    24  41  63  174 12  4
39.5    21  45  102 291 12  17
39.5    17  26  69  300 16  79
39.5    13  46  151 526 14  14
```

Despite I manage to get the correlation scores for the first column ("Latitude") against the others with

```
corrScores <- cor(Latitude, mydata[2:14429])
```

I need to get a list of the p-values by applying the function `cor.test(x, y,...)$p.value`

How can I do that without getting the error `'x' and 'y' must have the same length`?

Comment: I think R's `cor.test` only works with vectors. If the `x` and `y` used in `cor.test` above is `Latitude` and `mydata[2:14429]` - that would explain the error.

Comment: Note that these p-values are wrong though, you need to correct for multiple comparisons!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sapply`:

```
sapply(mydata[-1], function(y) cor.test(mydata$Latitude, y)$p.value)

#   comp48109   comp48326   comp48827   comp49708   comp48407   comp48912 
# 0.331584624 0.020971913 0.663194866 0.544407919 0.005375973 0.656831836
```

Here, `mydata[-1]` means: All columns of `mydata` except the first one.

Comment: Thanks! very appreciated! I need to study a bit more R. Cheers